# How to create custom taxonomy page? or custom archive page of custom taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I am using WooCommerce plugin.

I have this custom taxonomy under a product called "Merk".

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x('Merk', 'taxonomy general name'),
    'singular_name'              => _x('Merk', 'taxonomy singular name'),
    'search_items'               => __('Search Merk'),
    // Add other labels as needed
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_admin_column'     => true,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'merk'),
    'public'                =>  true,
    'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
    'has_archive'           =>  true
);

register_taxonomy('merk', 'product', $args);
```

Now I want to create an archive page of `merk` where I want to display all products from all terms under `merk`

I have tried creating by `archive-merk` and `taxonomy-merk.php`. no success.

I want to access that page by this URL https://www.example.com/shop/merk/

same for their term https://www.example.com/shop/merk/test

is there any way to do it?

Comment: Woocommerce uses own templates - https://woo.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: @Snuffy I have tried it but it's not working.  this `https://www.example.com/merk/` and this `https://www.example.com/shop/merk/` URLs give me 404

Comment: Create taxonomy-product-merk.php file in your theme/woocommerce folder and copy content of taxonomy-product-cat.php for example. This will give you access to domain.com/merk/123 . To have archive page for domain.com/merk you need to register page template and create page with this slug - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ in this template add your query or other content you want. or create template file archive-merk.php and do your logic there.